# VSCode hides folder contents when certain files are opened

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an angular project open in VSCode, but whenever I activate certain file tabs it hides every file & folder inside my `src/` directory!

Here's a screen recording of what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrB3B.jpg

No other folders are affected, and nothing is actually chnaged in the `src/` folder.  I can seect a `*.ts` file, close VSCode, and then re-open it with that `*.ts` file active and the folder contents shows again until I activate a tab that does this again.

This is extremely annoying and I've never seen this happen before.  let me know if you need any other information to help diagnose this issue.

---

Edit: My installed extensions are as follows:

- [**Angular Language Service** 0.1.11](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)
- [**AutoHotkey** 0.2.2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-autohotkey)
- [**C#** 1.18.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp)
- [**Code Spell Checker** v1.6.10](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker)
- [**Hosts Language** v1.1.1](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tommasov.hosts)
- [**npm** v0.3.5](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.vscode-npm-script)
- [**npm Intellisense** v1.3.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.npm-intellisense)
- [**Prettify JSON** v0.0.3](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohsen1.prettify-json)
- [**stylelint** v0.48.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shinnn.stylelint)
- [**TSLint** v1.0.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin)

Comment: Considered [opening an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues)? This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I thought about it, but wanted to post here first just in case. They suggested trying to reproduce it by launching it with extensions disabled `code --disable-extensions`, and I could not reproduce it.  Then back to normal with extensions enabled and now I can't get it to happen again!

Comment: Sounds like it's possibly related to extensions then. Can you share the ones you have installed

Comment: yes, updated my question to list my extensions now